# ASP.NET MVC3 conditional validation - checkbox > editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, checkbox, editor

I would like to have a bool field and and a string field in my Model and not having any validation attributes on them.
But in the view I would like to have the required field validation on the Editor if the Checkbox is checked.

How do I do this please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use the data annotations attributes and follow any of this option.

1. Clear the errors from the modelstate dictionary for that field inside the action
2. Use the conditional validation library created by [simon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx).

Ex.

```
public class ValidationSample
{
    [RequiredIf("PropertyValidationDependsOn", true)]
    public string PropertyToValidate { get; set; }

    public bool PropertyValidationDependsOn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I accept this as an answer cause you can do what I have asked for this way but I don't really like Simon's solution. It has no client side validation and if you do Model first approach in your development it is creating both dependent fields as required (not null) in the database. I still haven't found the solution that is complete in all these aspects.